# How to setup a python feeder to connect to a Spark Dstream

Tags: python, apache-spark, dstream

This is more of a conceptual question at this point. As a part of a class assignment, we are given a python script that writes data to stdout. The first step in the assignment is to setup this python feeder to feed into a Spark DStream.

I've been reading up on documentation on how to append this but not sure what this step exactly involves. Would appreciate any pointer to relevant info & happy to provide any further info. Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.